# DropDownList doesn't Fire Event on SelectedIndexChanged Using Databind in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, data-binding, drop-down-menu

I have the following dropdownlist:

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/myMasterPage.master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="testdropdown.aspx.cs" Inherits="testdropdown" %>

<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="head" Runat="Server">
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder2" Runat="Server">
    <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text=""></asp:Label>
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="Content3" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder1" Runat="Server">
    <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlDeliveryAddresses" runat="server" 
        DataTextField="delAddressShort" DataValueField="delID" 
        onselecteddindexchanged="ddlDeliveryAddresses_SelectedIndexChanged"
        AppendDataBoundItems="True" 
        AutoPostBack="True">
        <asp:ListItem Selected='True' Text='--select--' Value='-1'></asp:ListItem>    
    </asp:DropDownList>
</asp:Content>
```

And this code behind:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            SqlConnection conn;
            SqlCommand comm;
            SqlDataReader reader;

            conn = new SqlConnection(iceConns.iconn);
            comm = new SqlCommand("Customers.sl_DeliverybyBillID", conn);
            comm.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            comm.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@billID", SqlDbType.Int));
            comm.Parameters["@billID"].Value = 160;

            conn.Open();
            reader = comm.ExecuteReader();
            ddlDeliveryAddresses.DataSource = reader;
            ddlDeliveryAddresses.DataBind();
            reader.Close();
        }
    }
    protected void ddlDeliveryAddresses_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Label1.Text = ddlDeliveryAddresses.SelectedItem.Text;
    }
```

No matter what I do I can't populate the label. All works great if I replace the databind with static listitems! I've tried pretty much all the suggestions around, but nothing works (well not for me anyway!).

Comment: Your title is misleading, from what I gather the even _is_ actually firing, but the event handling code is malfunctioning in some way. Other than that, have you made certain that the procedure is returning something, anything?

Comment: I would set the DropDownList's [DataValueField](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.listcontrol.datavaluefield.aspx). I assume that it's used to detect if the value has changed across postbacks. By the way, is ViewState enabled at all for this control?

Comment: @Mr Disappointment - Sorry I tried to describe it the best I could. I don't think the event is being called as the breakpoint I placed there is being reached (hope that's the right terminology!)

Comment: go to the properties of the dropdownlist and see if the event actually has the method associated with it.(My guess is it is ,but u can check it anyway.) Label1.Text = ddlDeliveryAddresses.SelectedValue;

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your code says `onselecteddindexchanged`, it should be `OnSelectedIndexChanged`.

The casing should not matter, but notice the extra "d" after `onselected...`

Comment: My mistake, apologies; however, you might want to make use of the excellent editor we have here to make your answer more clear. Indeed I have removed the down-vote, in fact reversing it to an up-vote due to your eagle eye!